# Is it possible to allow a member group access to view a channel in the control panel but not publish/edit entries in it

Tags: members, users

I need to allow a member group to only view some channels (among others) in the control panel but only be able to edit some of those channels.

But as far as I can see there is no way to assign editing permissions per channel, right? I can allow editing for all channels the member group has access to or or nothing.

Comment: Are you looking to restrict access for users who have acces to the control panel or for users interacting with entries via stand alone entry forms (SAEFs)?

Comment: Yes, I need this only in CP, no front-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign which channels a member group can edit using the [channel assignment section](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#channel-assignment) of the member groups permissions screen. This will restrict the member groups access for posting/editing both in the CP and via stand alone entry forms.

You can also then use the [Channel Posting and Editing Privileges](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#channel-posting-and-editing-privileges) controls to determine whether CP users can edit/delete their own entries and view/edit/delete those of others.

However, **it is not possible to make a channel accessible as "read only" for a member group while allowing them editing permissions on another (as I think you are looking to do) using native functionality**. Once you set ""Can edit entries authored by others" for a member group they will have the ability to edit entries in all channels they have access to.

That said, you could still get very close to what you want by either using a [custom status group](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/statuses_edit.html) and setting permissions so that editors cannot make entries live even if they can edit them, or by using a custom extension to prevent members of your editor group from submitting entries in your chosen channel. The hook you would want for this is [entry_submission_start](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#entry-submission-start)

Comment: Ok, but that is general, as I need only view permission on one (no new posting) channel, and edit on another.

Comment: do you mean view entries via the Control Panel or on the front end of your site? If you only want them to view entries could you not just use a template (with permissions) for that?

Comment: I meant only to CP. That group is for editors and I need to allow them to view articles Channel, but without option for edit/submit. View works (they can see them in Edit list), but they cannot open it to view the article (I guess that was disabled buy "no edit"), not sure if its possible to "open" an entry and disable posting/submitting thou.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your clarification

Comment: Yeah, as I can see EE permissions are very very limited about that. I'm using custom statuses but this request is a little bit particular.

"While you can easily set things up so that a member group can view entries authored by others but not edit them (ie set "Can view channel entries authored by others" but not "Can edit entries authored by others"), members of this group will still be able to post entries to that channel."
-hm, I tried that and I get "You are not authorized to access", not sure if this is a bug or feature, using EE2.2.2

Comment: Sorry you were right, I made an error which I have corrected. Anyway, given that you need users in your editor group to be able to edit entries in some channels that wouldn't be an option _even if it worked_. Sorry for the mistake anyway.

Comment: Yes, because if I setup right one channel the other one have more permissions that it should. It would be awesome to have a choice under each channel what type of edit/view perrmission you want to add. atm custom develompent is not on the table, but its good to know that there are still other options as this is not possible out-of-box

Answer (score 2):

I believe for that level of specificity, you would need a separate workflow module. I believe [BetterWorkFlow](http://betterworkflow.electricputty.co.uk) by ElectricPutty is possibly what you are looking for.

Generally, in EE, once a channel is accessible, the privileges are closer to all or none. We've set business rules around editing before, but haven't really enforced them with the technology, accept for access. But we've been looking at BetterWorkFlow for a new project, where the client does require more control, and some of the staff wouldn't be inclined to stay within the limits of just business rules.

Comment: I will check it. thanx!